# How to login to gcloud using access token that is already received during sso login

Tags: gcloud

I do a SSO login to my node application using google and I have the access token. Now I want to execute few gcloud and docker commands in a shell. How do I initalize the gcloud in the shell using this access token and run docker commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [gcloud authenticated commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) using:

```
gcloud auth login [ACCOUNT]
```

Where **[ACCOUNT]** is the user account used for authorization. In case you want to [authenticate using a **service account**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account):

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE
```

Where **[ACCOUNT]** is the email address of the service account and **KEY_FILE** is the path to the private key file.

This will generate an access token and store it somewhere on the gcloud configuration files, that's the token it will use for all the API calls the tool makes on the background.

If you already have the access token, you can directly make the API calls using the proper HTTP methods. However you cannot "login" into gcloud using an access token.

Also the command "gcloud docker" is [deprecated for Docker client versions above 18.03](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices#_gcloud_docker_and_docker_clients_above_version_1803) . You should use ["configure-docker"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker) :

```
gcloud auth configure-docker [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```